# building html/php vs DOM/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call.  responseText is returned using the while loop below.  Everything works fine except the embedded javascript is not loaded.  My solution is to build as much of the html as I can on the client side using javascript.  What is the simplest way I can build this xhtml all on the client.  The simplest way would be to createElement('div') and add all these elements individually.  This is what I'm currently doing.  But because the code below failed, I wanted to know if this is a good solution.  More importantly is there a script out there that takes html and converts it to javascript, that would be ideal I'm guessing.

```
while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
  {
  $date = date('M j \a\t g:i:s a', $a[time]);
  echo  "<div class=\"Bb2b\"><img class=\"a\" src=\"p/$a[email].jpg\" alt=\"\"/><a class=\"a\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">$a[fname] posted <script type=\"text/javascript\">v0($a[time],$time)</script></a><br/><p class=\"c\">$a[message]</p></div>";
  }
```

Comment: after you created the div and added the html code, what are you doing with the div? you must insert it somewhere in the page

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behaviour that the javascript does not execute in dynamically changed .innerHTML - you just insert it into the page DOM. You need to execute such fragment manualy using eval(). However you say want to build the xhtml on the client side - which seems to be the exact oposite of what you are doing (you generate a lot of HTML in PHP).

I would suggest that you use JSON for transfering the data - in PHP you can directly convert a variable into JSON string using json_encode() function. That way your code could look like

```
while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
 {
  $a[date] = date('M j \a\t g:i:s a', $a[time]);
  echo json_encode($a);
}
```

On the client side, you can use JQuery (or any other decent AJAX library) to parse the string directly into JS objects. This would have the advantage of lowering the amount of transfered data and eliminating a number of security problems which are likely to occur when using eval.

Comment: thank you I updated my question to make a bit more sense.  so one can use eval but for best practice build it out into JS objects?  Is this correct?  Also do you have a link on how I can use JQuery or similar to do this instead of writing fromt the ground up?

Answer (score 0):

eval did not work as a temp fix..as a more involve temp fixed...I'm just going to load the html into the dom using this snippet

```
// HTML string 
var s = 'responseHTML'; 

var div = document.createElement('div'); 
div.innerHTML = s; 
var elements = div.childNodes;
```

Later I will just send the data and build it up in the DOM as a final solution to reduce overhead of sending html structure.